# Windows 8 adaptive brightness broken - reversed

Tags: windows-8, lenovo-laptop, brightness

My Lenovo Yoga 2 13 with Windows 8.1 has an annoying auto-brightness feature that dims the screen when the content is dark and increases the brightness when the content is light. This makes web-browsing, reading or gaming in the dark annoying, because I'd expect it to do THE EXACT OPPOSITE. Is there a way to make it dim the screen on bright content instead?

Comment: Have you tried changing the power profile?

Comment: yes, the best I can achieve is to disable brightness changing at all, but I'd welcome finding a way to reverse its logic actually

Comment: Does Lenovo install software to handle this feature?  Because there are two different software at play normally.  The OEM software that provides power mangement features and Windows own power mangement.  The first can be installed and likely is the culprit, you fix it, by getting rid of the problem software.  The other can't be removed and does not have a bug, so if it still happens, its likely a hardware problem.